# ¿Qué significado tiene la forma "de + infinitivo"?

Tags: gramática

No sé en qué situación se puede usar la siguiente forma:

> De comprarlo, cómpralo ya.

La frase de arriba tiene el sentido de: Si vas a comprarlo, cómpralo ya.

¿Cuál es más formal?

Comment: Es una forma corta de decir "si has de comprarlo, hazlo/cómpralo ya"

Answer (score 2):

La construcción "de" + infinitivo tiene el sentido de "en caso de" + infinitivo.

La oración:

- De comprarlo, cómpralo ya. (que no suena demasiado bien)

podría equiparsarse a:

- En caso de (querer) comprarlo, hazlo ahora mismo.